# What's the best way to create key events in HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, keyboard

Please suggest the best way to create key events for HTML5 canvas. I don't prefer any library, but if you think that it's the best way then go answer it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you just want to be able to execute specific functions when a key (such as "W") is pressed?

Comment: in my visual-js game engine i implement canvas-object oriented events . Where is virtual keyboard for canvas app : http://jsfiddle.net/zlatnaspirala/0u5j1ap8/

Comment: You should re-title the question. It seems it is not events what you want to create, but an EventHandler which triggers actions based on events (which all responses here implicitly describe as generated by the user via the keyboard).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This will return the key code:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="background:green"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('keydown',this.check,false);

function check(e) {
    alert(e.keyCode);
}
</script>
```

If you would like a demonstration of different things being done based on key:

```
function check(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode;
    //Up arrow pressed
    if (code == 38)
        alert("You pressed the Up arrow key");
    else
        alert("You pressed some other key I don't really care about.");
}
```

Or if you have a long list of keys you'll be using, do it in a switch case:

```
function check(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode;
    switch (code) {
        case 37: alert("Left"); break; //Left key
        case 38: alert("Up"); break; //Up key
        case 39: alert("Right"); break; //Right key
        case 40: alert("Down"); break; //Down key
        default: alert(code); //Everything else
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you just bind one key? example up arrow. Sorry newb question

Comment: I.e. only listen for that key? Sadly, no. The best you can do is check its key code, if the key code matches 38: do whatever, if it doesn't: do nothing.

Comment: Just want to comment that if you have multiple canvases, you are going to need to bind events to the specific canvas. Setting a tabindex on the canvas element allows for it to accept keyevents when focused.

Comment: Just to note it's usually better to use keyup rather than keydown - more stable.

Comment: this isnt correct answer, the question was the canvas not the window

Answer (score 12):

If you want to set key event handling on the `<canvas>` itself (not the `window` or `document`), set a tabindex on the `<canvas>` element. Note that the canvas will need to be in focus on to catch key events.

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('game').addEventListener('keypress', handleKeyPress);
    function handleKeyPress(e) { ... }
</script>
<canvas id="game" tabindex="1" width="350" height="200">
</canvas>
```

This is how it is done on the [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/learning/basic/keyboardfunctions/) website.

If you don't want a border to appear when you click on the canvas, set its style to `outline: none`.

Comment: How do you set a tab index?

Comment: @ncmathsadist by 'set' I mean, add the html attribute 'tabindex' to the `canvas` tag and give it an integer value. Tabindexes themselves are outside the scope of this question: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

Comment: "keypress event" deprecated 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event

Answer (score 2):

I'm writing a Canvas game, and I use the default `.addEventListener` and shift through the `event.keyCode`s that come with it. Further, I don't listen for key events on the Canvas element its self, rather just set the listener to the window.

```
window.addEventListener('keyup',keyUpListener,false);
window.addEventListener('keydown',keyDownListener,false);
```

Comment: Could you fire an alert with up arrow (38). Thanks.

Comment: Is it a good idea to work with window events? What if someone wants to do something outside of your game but in the same window, like write a comment?

Comment: @erikb85 in that case you may need to disable the event listeners when the user focuses on the input area.

Comment: This is the nub of the issue.  Only the window can "hear" key events.  Its listener, however, can alter the state of elements within the page.