# Adding an eventListener for key presses to HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to add a feature where you can add letters as you type them to the random set of flowing stars. I've tried so many things, and cannot for the life of me figure it out. Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Space</title>
  </head>

<style>

</style>

<body>
<div>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>

    <audio id="audio" controls>
        <source src="song.m4a" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>

<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;
var xCirc;
var yCirc;
var rCirc;
var animate = true;
var shapes = ['circle', 'square', 'triangle', 'heart', 'star'];
var shape = 0;
var song = document.getElementById("audio");
song.autoplay = true;
song.load();

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

makeParticles();
//makeShapes();

function click(){
    shape++;
    if (shape > shapes.length - 1){
        shape = 0;
    }

    var pType = shapes[shape];
    for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++){
        particles[i].particleType = pType;
    }
}

function doKeyDown(evt){

}

start();


function makeParticles() {
    xCenter = canvas.width/2;
    yCenter = canvas.height/2;
    particles = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        particles.push(new Particle(shapes[shape]));
    }
}

function Circle(r1, r2, gradient2) {
    var r1 = 150;
    var r2 = canvas.width - (canvas.width/2);
    var gradient1 = context.createRadialGradient(width/2, height/2, r1, width/2, height/2, r2);

    gradient1.addColorStop(0, "#46C7C7");
    gradient1.addColorStop(1, "#0C090A");
    context.fillStyle = gradient1;
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var gradient2 = context.createRadialGradient(width/2, height/2, 120, width/2, height/2, 150);
    gradient2.addColorStop(0, "black");
    gradient2.addColorStop(.5, "#008080");
    gradient2.addColorStop(1, "#54C571");

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(width/2, height/2, 150, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    context.fillStyle = gradient2;
    context.fill();
}

function start() {

    if(animate){
        window.requestAnimationFrame(start);
    }

    draw();
    moveParticles();
    canvas.addEventListener("click", click);
    canvas.addEventListener("keypress", doKeyDown, true);
    console.log(num);
}



function Particle() {
    this.x = Math.floor((Math.random() * canvas.width) + 1);
    this.y = Math.floor((Math.random() * canvas.height) + 1);
    this.z = Math.floor((Math.random() * canvas.width));

    var grad = context.createRadialGradient(this.x, this.y, Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1), this.x, this.y, Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1));
    var colors = ["#4CC417", "#3EA055", "#54C571", "#41A317", "#46C7C7", "#4EE2EC", "#00FFFF", "#008080", "#57FEFF", "#3BB9FF", "#1F45FC"];

    grad.addColorStop(0, colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)]);
    grad.addColorStop(1, colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)]);
    this.color = grad;
    this.radius = 1;

    this.draw = function() {
        xP = (xCenter - this.x) * (canvas.width/this.z);
        xP += xCenter;
        yP = (yCenter - this.y) * (canvas.width/this.z);
        yP += yCenter;
        rP = (canvas.width/this.z);

        switch (this.particleType) {
            case 'circle':
                context.beginPath();
                context.arc(xP, yP, rP, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
                context.fillStyle = this.color;
                context.fill();
                break;
            case 'square':
                context.beginPath();
                context.rect(xP, yP, rP * 3, rP * 3);
                context.fillStyle = this.color;
                context.fill();
                break;
            case 'triangle':
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(xP, yP);
                context.lineTo(xP + (rP * 2), yP + (rP * 2));
                context.lineTo(xP - (rP * 2), yP + (rP * 2));
                context.fillStyle = this.color;
                context.fill();
                break;
            case 'heart':
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(xP, yP - (rP * 2));
                context.bezierCurveTo(xP - (rP * 6), yP - (rP * 11), xP - (rP * 2), yP - (rP * 12), xP, yP - (rP * 7));
                context.bezierCurveTo(xP + (rP * 2), yP - (rP * 12), xP + (rP * 6), yP - (rP * 11), xP, yP - (rP * 2));
                context.fillStyle = this.color;
                context.fill();
                break;
            case 'star':
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(xP, yP);
                context.lineTo(xP - (rP * 1), yP + (rP * 3));
                context.lineTo(xP - (rP * 4), yP + (rP * 3));
                context.lineTo(xP - (rP * 2), yP + (rP * 6));
                context.lineTo(xP - (rP * 3), yP + (rP * 9));
                context.lineTo(xP, yP + (rP * 7));
                context.lineTo(xP + (rP * 3), yP + (rP * 9));
                context.lineTo(xP + (rP * 2), yP + (rP * 6));
                context.lineTo(xP + (rP * 4), yP + (rP * 3));
                context.lineTo(xP + (rP * 1), yP + (rP * 3));
                context.fillStyle = this.color;
                context.fill();
                break;
        }
    }
}

function draw() {   

    Circle();

    for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++){
        var p = particles[i].draw();
            //context.fillStyle = p.color;
            //context.fillText("Black Hole Sun", xP, yP);



    }

}

function clearCanvas() {

    canvas.width = canvas.width;

}

function moveParticles() {

    for (var j = 0; j < particles.length; j++){
        var p = particles[j];
        p.z -= 1;
        if (p.z <= 0){
            p.z = canvas.width;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241113/whats-the-best-way-to-create-key-events-in-html5-canvas)? Also, might be a good idea to isolate your specific issue instead of posting so much code, since it is easier for people to help out!

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question to include a description of what's happening now instead of the desired behavior. (Do you get an error, does it fail silently, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't really state actually what you want,

I have just done a very small fix to your code, I have attached the eventlistener to the document and not the canvas.

Here is the jsFiddle and the snippet of code

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/CanvasCode/auyybsj6/

javascript

```
function doKeyDown(evt) {
  alert(event.keyCode);
}

...

function start() {

  if (animate) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(start);
  }

  draw();
  moveParticles();
  canvas.addEventListener("click", click);
  document.addEventListener("keypress", doKeyDown, false);
  console.log(num);
}
```