# JS/JQuery: key press not detected on HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-canvas

In my webpage, I'm trying to trigger an alert whenever a key is pressed on the canvas. However, no event is triggered when a key is pressed in the canvas. Below is my HTML, CSS, and JavaScript/JQuery code.

**HTML**:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>
```

**CSS**:

```
#myCanvas {
  display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript/JQuery**:

```
document.getElementById("defaultCanvas1").addEventListener("keypress", handleKeyPress);

function handleKeyPress(e) {
    alert("keyPressed!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress);` to trigger your event when you press the key.

[What's the best way to create key events in HTML5 canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241113/whats-the-best-way-to-create-key-events-in-html5-canvas)

Comment: @Adam Sorry my mistake. you want to call it on window element. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First focus the canvas with `tabindex="1"` and `canvas.focus()`. Try the following way:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  canvas.focus();
  canvas.addEventListener("keypress", handleKeyPress);
  function handleKeyPress(e) {
    alert("keyPressed!");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;" tabindex="1">
</canvas>
```

**OR:** You can try [addEventListener for keydown on Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886286/addeventlistener-for-keydown-on-canvas)